# problema con una funcion y un item

Tags: c++, dev-c++

estuve programando en c++ para mi servidor de juegos una funcion que permite usar un quiver, para guardar flechas y poder dispararlas desde ahi, sin embargo. estoy intentando que solo se puedan poner items de amunition dentro del quiver. mas este codigo hace todo lo contrario no me deja meter nada en las mochilas convencionales solo en el quiver.

```
if (getID() != ITEM_QUIVER && item->getAmmoType() != AMMO_NONE){
        return RETURNVALUE_THISISIMPOSSIBLE;
    }
```

y si lo pongo asi

```
if (getID() == ITEM_QUIVER && item->getAmmoType() == AMMO_NONE){
        return RETURNVALUE_THISISIMPOSSIBLE;
    }
```

simplemente no filtra que se puedan agregar solo amunition, please ayuda bro

---

aver amigo quizas tienes razon, voy a explicarlo de mejor forma.

tengo un ot server de open tibia. resulta que quiero implementar la quiver, lo cual ya realize. este es el codigo con el que realize el quiver.

```
Item* Player::getAmmunition() const
{
    Item* item = inventory[CONST_SLOT_AMMO];
    if (!item)
        return nullptr;

    if (Container *container = item->getContainer()) {
        if (item->getID() != ITEM_QUIVER)
        return nullptr;

        Item* weapon = getWeapon();
        const ItemType& it = Item::items[weapon->getID()];
        for (ContainerIterator iter = container->iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.advance()) {
            const ItemType& itr = Item::items[(*iter)->getID()];
            if (itr.ammoType == it.ammoType)
                return (*iter);
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```

hasta ahi funciona todo perfecto. nada que decir.

sin embargo, en mi juego hay funcion de mochilas. resulta que el item, quiero que solamente acepte solo municion, ningun otro item. por eso el codigo que publique antes.

sin embargo no logro hacerlo.

lo unico que logre con el codigo publicado anteriormente es que solo pueda echar items dentro. esta seria la funcion completa de addquery

```
ReturnValue Container::queryAdd(int32_t index, const Thing& thing, uint32_t count,
        uint32_t flags, Creature* actor/* = nullptr*/) const
{
    bool childIsOwner = hasBitSet(FLAG_CHILDISOWNER, flags);
    if (childIsOwner) {
        //a child container is querying, since we are the top container (not carried by a player)
        //just return with no error.
        return RETURNVALUE_NOERROR;
    }

    const Item* item = thing.getItem();
    if (item == nullptr) {
        return RETURNVALUE_NOTPOSSIBLE;
    }

    if (!item->isPickupable()) {
        return RETURNVALUE_CANNOTPICKUP;
    }

    if (item == this) {
        return RETURNVALUE_THISISIMPOSSIBLE;
    }
    
    if (getID() != ITEM_QUIVER && item->getAmmoType() != AMMO_NONE){
        return RETURNVALUE_THISISIMPOSSIBLE;
    }
    const Cylinder* cylinder = getParent();
    if (!hasBitSet(FLAG_NOLIMIT, flags)) {
        while (cylinder) {
            if (cylinder == &thing) {
                return RETURNVALUE_THISISIMPOSSIBLE;
            }

            cylinder = cylinder->getParent();
        }

        if (index == INDEX_WHEREEVER && size() >= capacity()) {
            return RETURNVALUE_CONTAINERNOTENOUGHROOM;
        }
    } else {
        while (cylinder) {
            if (cylinder == &thing) {
                return RETURNVALUE_THISISIMPOSSIBLE;
            }

            cylinder = cylinder->getParent();
        }
    }

    const Cylinder* topParent = getTopParent();
    if (topParent != this) {
        return topParent->queryAdd(INDEX_WHEREEVER, *item, count, flags | FLAG_CHILDISOWNER, actor);
    } else {
        return RETURNVALUE_NOERROR;
    }
}
```

ademas este codigo si lo escribo de esta manera

```
if (getName() == "Quiver" && (!(item->getSlotPosition() & SLOTP_AMMO) || item->getName() == "Quiver")) {
        return RETURNVALUE_NOTENOUGHROOM;
    }
```

funciona de manera inversa, osea no deja meter nada a ningun contenedor.

cualquier otra duda podrias ver aqui

https://github.com/TwistedScorpio/Nostalrius/tree/master/src

ese es el codigo completo del servidor el cual estoy modificando

Comment: La verdad es que con la poca información válida que das, lo más que te puedo decir es que la condición del `if` se cumple si las dos condiciones se cumplen a la vez, dado que el operador lógico entre ellas es `&&`. Del resto de la explicación, yo personalmente no entiendo nada. No sé los demás si sabrán de lo que hablas.

Answer (score 0):

La opción buena debería ser la segunda:

```
if (getID() == ITEM_QUIVER && item->getAmmoType() == AMMO_NONE){
    return RETURNVALUE_THISISIMPOSSIBLE;
}
```

Si no te funciona es posible que `item->getAmmoType()` no esté funcionando correctamente.

En cualquier caso, tal vez deberías pensar en implementar polimorfismo para simplificar las funciones